# How to display only specific data from an array in an input with Form::Select in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, forms, input

I have this array ( I displayed it with function dd() ), with multiple data, and I want to display only "name" data in input field.

[image]

That's how is looking now

[image]

And how I want to be displayed names.

[image]

That's my function from Controller that I push data to page.

```php
 private function needs()
    {
        $grades = Grade::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

        $subjects = Subject::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

        $students = User::students()->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

        $teachers = User::teachers()->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

        $goals = Goal::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

        $statuses = Status::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

        $formats = Format::all()->map->only(['id', 'name', 'students'])->values()->toArray();

        return compact('grades', 'subjects', 'students', 'teachers', 'goals', 'statuses', 'formats');
    }
```

And there is form from the page :

```php
<div class="form-group">
                {{ Form::label('format_id', 'Формат', ['class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right']) }}
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    {{ Form::select('format_id', [null => '--не выбран--'] + $formats, $data->format_id ?? 0, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'format_id']) }}
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with a little loop under the `$format` variable in your controller:

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($formats as $item) {
    array_push($arr, $item['name']);
}
$formats = $arr;
```

Or change this line like this:

```
$formats = array_column(
    Format::all()->map->only(['id', 'name', 'students'])->values()->toArray(),
    'name'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your $formats array to have key "id" and value "name":

```
{{ Form::select(
    'format_id',
    [null => '--не выбран--'] + array_combine(array_column($formats, 'id'), array_column($formats, 'name')),
    $data->format_id ?? 0,
    ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'format_id']
) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mapWithKeys() collection function to do so.

Exemple with formating an array to [id => name]:

```
$grades = Grade::all()->pluck('name', 'id')
            ->mapWithKeys(function ($grade) {
                return [$grade->id => $grade->name];
            })
            ->toArray();

// Or select instead of pluck
$grades = Grade::select('id', 'name')->get()
            ->mapWithKeys(function ($grade) {
                return [$grade->id => $grade->name];
            })
            ->toArray();
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-mapwithkeys